# Bloquear leitura, abertura e edição de arquivo

Tags: c#, .net

Como bloquear a abertura, leitura e edição de um arquivo pelo usuário durante o período em que a aplicação estiver rodando?

Uma aplicação tem um período de coleta de dados relativamente longo. Essa aplicação lê dados em tempo real. Os dados lidos são gravados em arquivo a cada minuto. No final da coleta de dados, devo liberar o arquivo para o usuário.  Uso o código abaixo para salvar os dados a cada minuto. Os atributos de arquivo *hidden* e *read only* não me ajudam!

```
string diret=saveFileDialog1.FileName;
Encoding sjisX=Encoding.GetEncoding("Shift_JIS");
StreamWriter arquivo=new StreamWriter(diret,true,sjisX);
arquivo.Write(tb_csv.Text); //salva os dados.
arquivo.Close(); // fecha o arquivo.

//fileProtec.Attributes=FileAttributes.Hidden; permite sua abertura, logo, não serve!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ao invés de criar o objeto `StreamWriter` com o caminho do arquivo, crie um [`FilesTream`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.io.filestream(v=vs.110).aspx) e o passe para o `StreamWriter`.

Por exemplo:

```
string diret = saveFileDialog1.FileName;
using (FileStream arquivo =  // Isso é o que realmente abre o arquivo. Não esqueça o using.
        File.Open(diret,
                  FileMode.OpenOrCreate,
                  FileAccess.ReadWrite,
                  FileShare.None)) {

    using (StreamWriter escritor = new StreamWriter(arquivo)) // esse objeto não é o arquivo, é quem escreve nele.
    {
        escritor.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End); // Posicionamos o cursor de escrita no final do arquivo.

        escritor.Write(tb_csv.Text);
        escritor.flush(); // Caso hajam dados em buffer ainda não escritos, forçamos sua escrita.

        escritor.Close();
    }
}
```

Isso bloqueia a leitura por outros processos por causa da assinatura do [método Open da classe File](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/y973b725(v=vs.110).aspx). Esse método consegue informar ao sistema operacional que você não deseja compartilhar o arquivo com outros processos, através de seu último parâmetro. Da [documentação oficial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.io.fileshare(v=vs.110).aspx):

> **FileShare.None:** Declina o compartilhamento do arquivo atual. Qualquer solicitação para abrir o arquivo (por esse processo ou por outro) falhará até que o arquivo seja fechado.

Comment: Mas, quando  der este comando   escritor.Close(); libera o arquivo ?

Comment: Mas, quando  der este comando   escritor.Close();    libera o arquivo ? 
A cada minuto, a app irá abrir o arquivo, gravar e fechar?
Com o código que uso atualmente; no intervalo de salvamento o arquivo pode ser aberto. Preciso que o arquivo fique fechado até o final da coleta de dados e que ao terminar libere o arquivo. Outra coisa, preciso de um plano de contingencia. Se o program travar ou se o computador for desligado da energia como acessar este arquivo?

Comment: @silviopontes sim, ao usar o método `Close` o arquivo é liberado. Acho que entendi o que você quer agora. **você nunca vai conseguir isso se continuar trabalhando com arquivos dessa forma.** Uma sugestão é gravar os dados em um banco de dados e gerar o arquivo apenas ao final da coleta de dados.

Comment: Estou fazendo isso, mas se o computador travar ou faltar energia eu perco os dados.

Comment: @silviopontes com um banco de dados isso não aconteceria.

Comment: Renan, como se usa esta solução que você diz de banco de dados? Outra coisa; se a maquina travar como eu recupero os dados e converto para csv?

Comment: @silviopontes isso é um assunto grande demais para comentários, então vou apenas dizer que você deve usar MySQL ou PostGRE (ambos gratuitos) ou MSSQL (a versão *Express* é gratuita). Se você precisa de preocupar com  máquinas travando então já começou mal - sua aplicação deveria estar na nuvem se é tão sensível assim - e para converter para CSV você usa o mesmo programa com o qual coleta dados (a conversão é por sua conta).

Comment: Agradecido, ajudou muito mesmo.